# Asp.Net MVC Controller / Ressource Manager: globalization issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

I experience some problems concerning `globalization` in `asp.net`.

Parts of the page are randomly in english instead of german.

See this code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> InterestingControllerMethod(Guid offeringRateId, Guid trainerId, DateTime? selectedDate)
        {

//de-DE
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(SlConst.DefaultCulture);

            var dateAndUtcTime = GetSelectedDateTime(selectedDate);

            var selectTimesTrainer = await QueryProcessor.ExecuteAsyncWithCache(new OfferingRateCourseSelectableTimesForTrainerQuery
            {
                BasketId = BasketId,
                OfferingRateId = offeringRateId,
                FirstBookableDateTime = dateAndUtcTime,
                LastBookableDateTime = dateAndUtcTime.GetEndOfDay(),
                CurrentDateTime = SlDateTime.CurrentDateTimeUtc(SlConst.DefaultTimeZoneTzdb),
                ForTrainerId = trainerId,
                CustomerId = CurrentUserId
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);


// this method actually uses ResourceManager

            var result = GetSelectTimesCourseForTrainer(selectTimesTrainer);

            return Json(result);
        }
```

But in the end I always got a mixed gui.

In debug mode it seems that the culture de-DE has not been assigned at all:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thx!

Comment: Could this be because of async task? I'd assume that the task is beeing set to it's original culture when the request returns to the caller..?

Comment: as it turns out it has been caused by making use of async await pattern. moving the set currentui culture statement right before GetSelectTimesCourseForTrainer solved the issue